# Save and Read class of arraylist of arraylist

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist, serializable

I'm new to this forum but also to Java, so excuse me if my question seems stupid.

For a project I have to create a program for a health center, so I've decided to go like this :

```
public class Laboratory implements Serializable {
protected static String labName;
protected static ArrayList<People> listPeople;
protected static ArrayList<File> listFile;
```

The tricky part is that every object File is also composed of an ArrayList of analyses...

```
public class File {
protected String loginPatient;
private ArrayList<Analyse> listAnalyses;
```

And I want to save it and read it so that every person in the arraylist listPeople and every file in the arraylist listFile would be saved everytime the program quits and loaded everytime the program started.

So as you see, I wanted to use Serializable but I don't get how I can use it on the whole class Laboratory, I've only seen it for ArrayList. Is it the best way to do so and if so, how ?
Furthermore, if an arraylist is composed of another arraylist does serializable work ?

Thanks again for your possible answers, and if you have any questions just tell me !
It's probably not the best way for this program to work so any advice is welcome ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Description of [interface Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) says `Serializability of a class is enabled by the class implementing the java.io.Serializable interface. Classes that do not implement this interface will not have any of their state serialized or deserialized. All subtypes of a serializable class are themselves serializable. The serialization interface has no methods or fields and serves only to identify the semantics of being serializable.`

Every member of your serializable class has to be serializable too to be serialized.

Have you considered saving the health center's information in the database? Using database would also keep to the minimum the amount of information needed to save or read each time the information changes. :)